# Android Emulator only able to upload 5 JPEG images

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am able to run 5 JPEG images on android Emulator. If I upload more than 5 image, emulator not able to start the activity.

Please Help...

This is my code for the ImageAdapter.. When I click on the Image mThumbIds(which is 150,150), it starts another activity. This happens only when I have 5 JPEG images in my array, if I have more than 5 JPEG images, program will crash..

I also tried adding png images, but the same problem.

I have been stuck on this for last two days..and still havent found any solution

```
 package com.example.first;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context mContext;
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.h18, R.drawable.h17, R.drawable.h16, R.drawable.h15, 



    };
    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageview;
        if(convertView == null){
            imageview = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageview.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150,150));
            imageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageview.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        }else{
            imageview = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        imageview.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageview;


    }



}
```

My Log cat shows following

```
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1965)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:660)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:616)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:349)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at com.example.first.ImageAdapter.getView(ImageAdapter.java:50)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1341)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.GridView.makeRow(GridView.java:341)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.GridView.fillDown(GridView.java:283)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.GridView.fillFromTop(GridView.java:417)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.GridView.layoutChildren(GridView.java:1229)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1994)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-28 21:54:33.645: E/AndroidRuntime(1213):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Which emulator, which version?  What error do you recieve?  Please be more specific

Comment: And can you show us your image adapter codes ? (if you use. If not, how can u loading images)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the size of those images are but I suspect they are much larger than 150x150 ?

You can load them up at a reduced resolution closer matching your 150dp imageviews with the following 2 functions.

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if(reqHeight + reqWidth == 0){
        Utils.logw("Bitmap decoded at full res due to width and height being zero.");
        return inSampleSize;
    }
    else if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

        // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
        // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
        // requested height and width.
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

and replace your call

```
imageview.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
```

with

```
imageview.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(mThumbIds[position], 150, 150));
```

Comment: K this worked, but it created another problem, it gives me blank screen. Image still opens up(assuming that 150,150 pic is there at its place). In another word, thumbs are behind the blank screen.

Comment: I can guarantee you the above functions are no causing the blank screen, it's production code.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an out of memory error.   This would likely be fixed in the emulator by adjusting the emulator RAM in the memory options.  You may also want to play with increasing the VM Heap.

What may also help you is to reduce the resolution of your resource images.  You can do this programatically as suggested by a different answer or just have some lower resolution images in your resources.